# Why is this trigger deleting all new records inserted?

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object

I have built a new trigger to prevent duplicate records from being created, but for some reason rather than delete duplicates, it deletes all new records.

Can anyone tell me why?

```
trigger ACPIDuplicateCheck on ProductInformation__c (after insert, after update) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Id> recordsToDelete = new List<Id>();

    for(ProductInformation__c a : Trigger.new){
        accountIds.add(a.Account__c);
    }

    Set<ProductInformation__c> prodInfo = new Set<ProductInformation__c>([SELECT Id, Name, Account__c, CheckBack__c, DateOffered__c, MasterProduct__c, Notes__c, Product__c, Status__c, SubProduct__c FROM ProductInformation__c WHERE Account__c IN :accountIds AND IsDeleted != true]);
    Set<ProductInformation__c> newProdInfo = new Set<ProductInformation__c>(Trigger.new);

    Set<ProductInformation__c> prodInfoToDelete = new Set<ProductInformation__c>();

    for(ProductInformation__c a : newProdInfo){
        for(ProductInformation__c b : prodInfo){
            if(a.Account__c == b.Account__c && a.Product__c == b.Product__c){
                if(a.Status__c == 'Not Offered'){
                    if( a.CheckBack__c == null && a.DateOffered__c == null && a.Notes__c == null){
                        prodInfoToDelete.add(a);
                        recordsToDelete.add(a.Id);
                    }
                }
                if(b.Status__c == 'Not Offered' || !prodInfoToDelete.contains(a)){
                    if( b.CheckBack__c == null && b.DateOffered__c == null && b.Notes__c == null){
                        prodInfoToDelete.add(b);
                        recordsToDelete.add(b.Id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    Database.delete(recordsToDelete);
```

Comment: This is because your query `prodInfo` returns all the existing `ProductInformation__c` objects. Even the ones which were just inserted. So your `if(a.Account__c == b.Account__c && a.Product__c == b.Product__c){` statement is always true once.

Comment: @MartinLezer wow I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem ! I hope you'll be able to resolve your problem.